Social app for younger people to increase their interest in elderly people
I am looking for a social network application for elderly people which would be structured as follows.
There is a big splash screen page with pictures inside circles arranged in a grid.
When you click on a profile, you see a set of topics (which, each person, talks about).
Under each topic, a list of (possibly, named) videos (where the person talks about the topic).
Topics could involve subjects including medication or medical treatment (including home setting, things to watch out for, remedies), cooking, children, or any other topic.
People, can even, share, pictures of meals (socialize based on sharing something they ate). Hopefully, they will be in a good enough mood to do so (if, they wish to do so
The stuff is published globally.
Users, can browse, elderly person, by location, and click on their picture to see what they want to share.
The elderly person could also optionally publish their needs or when they would like to receive a visit at home.
Thanks.
